# Where is MonoGame's API reference?

Tags: c#, monogame, documentation

I wanted to pick up Monogame, but I can't find documentation. All I see on GitHub is some tutorials. I'm looking for class reference like [this from XNA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203940.aspx).

Comment: You already found the XNA class reference. It would be nearly identical to the MonoGame class reference if it existed, so what exactly are you asking here?

Answer (score 3):

MonoGame's documentation portal is [here](http://www.monogame.net/documentation). They don't appear to currently have an API reference as of this writing.

I would venture to guess that this is because MonoGame's API tries to be identical to XNA's, so you can probably get away with just using XNA's API reference. The focus of the MonoGame project appears to be on longer-form documentation like tutorials and the like at the moment.

Comment: That's exactly right. MonoGame is intended to mimic the behaviour of XNA so the existing Microsoft XNA API reference should be sufficient. If it doesn't behave the same way it's either a bug or a platform specific unsupported feature. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203940.aspx

Comment: @JoshPetrie still trying to be identical? Does that mean there are some specific stuff MonoGame has which XNA doesn't have? Their site documentation is horrible but I've read worst documentations than this though.

Answer (score 0):

Monogame's documenation can be found on their site: http://monogame.net/documentation

They also have tutorials on their github page: https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/wiki/Tutorials

If you're looking for detailed documentation like Microsoft has, you're out of luck. Monogame is an opensource engine. Not a well funded company like Microsoft. Documentation is the last thing developers usually want to work on, so when they aren't being paid for it, it's the last thing (if ever) to get done.